# Read specific column data which is long type by using Spring Batch in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Folks..!!

Have a requirement to work on reading specific column data by using Spring batch. Well i am creating a spring batch application which has a requirement to read specific column.

In my csv file i have a column "msisdn", that field is mapped to an POJO. I want to read the values of "msisdn" no which is of Long data type.

well i am taking reference of below link.

[read only selective columns from csv file using spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075758/read-only-selective-columns-from-csv-file-using-spring-batch)

## Customer POJO

```
public class Customer {

    private String id_type;
    private String id_number;
    private String customer_name;
    private String email_address;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private String citizenship;
    private String address;
    private Long msisdn;
    private LocalDateTime kyc_date;
    private String kyc_level;
    private String goalscore;
    private String mobile_network;
}
```

I am using a CustomMapper class to implement this feature. As you can see CustomMapper class implements FieldSetMapper type. fieldSet method returns String[] Array and msisdn is of Long type.Not able to understand how to get all values in msisdn column as fieldSet is only giving String[] type of data.

```
CustomMapper
============
public class CustomMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        String[] custArray = null;
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setMsisdn(fieldSet.get);
        return null;
    }

}
```

[image: The way msisdn store is store in csv below format.i want to read the data one by one in same format. Please refer attached screenshot.]

please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fieldSet.readLong(int index)` or `fieldSet.readLong(String name)` to select a field by name or index from the field set. Obviously this field should have been selected when parsing the file in your item reader.

Comment: well if we write CustomFieldSetMapper, do we have to mention fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Customer.class); I have doubt on this. Could you please clarify me on this?

Comment: No, if you have a custom mapper, you just need to set it in your `FlatFileItemReader`'s configuration: `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder.fieldSetMapper(new CustomMapper())`

Comment: Well i have used like this.FieldSetMapper<Customer> fieldSetmapper = new FieldSetMapper<Customer>() {

   @Override
   public Customer mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setMsisdn(fieldSet.readLong("msisdn"));
    return customer;
   }
  };

  linemapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetmapper);

Comment: yes It looks good like that, but to be sure please edit your question and add code instead of adding it in comments.

Comment: Sure i will be following the the standards which you have mention in your comment @Mahmoud Ben Hassine